OSError errno 5 login/logout error on AWS
The error image
I have deployed my Django project to the AWS server. The projects runs fine for the first few hours but then starts giving this OSError errno 5 login/logout error. The project runs fine locally and even for extended hours but gives issue when deployed to AWS. Any help?
I cannot understand how to even start resolving this issue. I tried checking on my AWS ec2 server but everything is fine over there.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can we see your REST FRAMEWORK conf in settings.py? Also your viewsets and routers(URLs) ?
